# Powershell: Get-TSSession - Cannot access ConnectedTime & DisconnectedTime properties of obj on Windows Server 2012 that I can on Windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012

I'm using Shay's (fantastic!) PSTerminalServices Powershell module for finding disconnected sessions throughout our TS farm. I developed the script (with help from Stackoverflow!) on my Windows 7 x64 workstation (using PS ISE x86). I've since deployed the code to my new Windows 2012 process server where I tested it (again in ISE x86).... and it threw exceptions.

The code (that works in Windows 7) is:

```
#variables
$SubjectLine = "Disconnected Session Discovered on Terminal Server"  
$Sender = "noreply@example.com"
$Recipient = "test@example.com"
$Attachment = ""
$Exceptions = ""

$BodyPart1 = "You are being sent this email because you have a disconnected session on a Terminal Server. The session is as follows: `r`n`r`n"
$BodyPart3 = "Please log back on to this terminal server, close all data entry systems and log off properly (via the Start menu). Please do not click the the top-right X as this only closes the remote window. Following this procedure will help prevent data/index corruption and other work-stopping issues. `r`n`r`n Thank you"

#terminalservers.txt contains a list of terminal servers to check
$tsservers = Get-Content ".\terminalservers.txt"

foreach ($i in $tsservers){
    Get-TSSession -ComputerName $i | ? { $_.state -eq "Disconnected" } | % {
        $username   = $_ | select -ExpandProperty UserName
        $server     = $_ | select -ExpandProperty Server
        #>>>>THESE next two lines work on Windows 7 but not on Server 2012...?<<<<
        $connect    = $_ | select -ExpandProperty ConnectTime
        $disconnect = $_ | select -ExpandProperty DisconnectTime

        $query = "SELECT * from ds_user where ds_sAMAccountName='$username'"
        $user = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -Namespace "root\Directory\LDAP"
        $user.DS_mail

        #build email body
        Body = $BodyPart1 + "Username: " + $username + "`r`n" + "Terminal Server Name: " + $server.ServerName + "`r`n" + "Connect Time: " + $connect.DateTime + "`r`n" + "Disconnect Time: " + $disconnect.DateTime + "`r`n`r`n`r`n" + $BodyPart3

        #send email to user
        SendMail $SubjectLine $Body $Sender $Recipient 

    }
}
```

The two properties that I cannot retrieve within Windows 2012 are: ConnectTime and DisconnectTime. When run on Server 2012 I receive the error:

> select : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. 
>   Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
>   At C:\somefolder\terminal_server_session_reporter.ps1:39 char:26
>   +       $connect    = $_ | select -ExpandProperty ConnectTime
>   +                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], PSArgument 
>      NullException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Selec 
>      tObjectCommand
>
> select : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. 
>   Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
>   At C:\somefolder\terminal_server_session_reporter.ps1:39 char:26
>   +       $connect    = $_ | select -ExpandProperty ConnectTime
>   +                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], PSArgument 
>      NullException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Selec 
>      tObjectCommand

It's just these two properties that cause problems. If I comment them out the code runs fine on Server 2012. I've confirmed that I'm running the same version of PSTerminalServices module as well as .NET Framework 4 and cassia.dll. Both machines are running the same version of Powershell 3. I could deploy this code with these two properties omitted... but they're actually quite helpful and I would like to include them if at all possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this would not work on Server 2012, or how to fix it?

Oh, I also wanted to mention that the following code DOES work on Server 2012:

```
Get-TSSession -computername terminalserver1 | Select ConnectedTime, DisconnectedTime
```

...so it would seem that the properties are usable when accessed in that manner... I'm baffled.

EDIT 1: I've just confirmed that the same problem exists on Windows Server 2008 R2 (up to date with same versions of all modules, frameworks, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in powershell (v1, v2 and 3), when a property is empty and you use ExpandProperty to read it, it returns this error.